# I need help with a Rails ActiveRecord Join - I know how to do it in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have 2 tables I need to join but the user_id column value is not the same in both tables.  So I want to do something like this:

In my controller `4` will be substituted with `current_user.id`

`select * from sites join pickups on sites.id = pickups.site_id where sites.user_id = '4'`

But using an ActiveRecord Find.

Here are my associations:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pickups

class Pickup < ActiveRecord::Base  
 belongs_to :site   
 belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one  :profile
    has_many :pickups
    has_many :sites
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said "user_id column value is not the same in both tables". What is the schema of your table? What are the column names?

Comment: I mean that the pickups can be associated with a different user than the sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this to your user model:

```
has_many :site_pickups, :through => :sites, :source => :pickups
```

You can do

```
current_user.site_pickups
```

Comment: In my model I had to do :
`has_many :site_pickups, :through => :sites, :source => :pickups`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sites = current_user.sites.find(:all, :include => [:pickup])
```